# Reverse for 'detailed_view' with no arguments not found

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

Following is my code from views.py

```
from . import views

app_name = 'blogs'

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.blogs_home, name='blogs'),
   path('<int:post_id>', views.single_blog, name='detailed_view'),
]
```

Following code is from views.py

```
def single_blog(request,post_id):
   blog_single = Blogs.objects.get(id=post_id)
   context = {'blog_single': blog_single}
   template = 'blog_home.html'

   return render(request, template, context)
```

and html is given below

```
{% for b in blogs %}
<div>
    <h1><a href="{% url 'blogs:detailed_view' id=b.id %}">{{ b.title }}</a></h1>
    <p>{{ b.body }}</p>
    <aside>{{ b.date }}</aside>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

However, it returns the error reverse for 'detailed_view' with no arguments not found.

Can you please explain and correct. Thank you

Jeff

Comment: Please show the exact error and full traceback.

Comment: show `blogs_home` view as well

Answer (score 1):

Change the line in html to :

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'blogs:detailed_view' post_id=b.id %}">{{ b.title }}</a></h1>
```